# steam trade offer manager newOffer not working on limited account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

friendMessage is working fine, being able to receive any messages from anyone. But I'm having problems with newOffer, sending offers and never getting their information to be displayed on the terminal. Is this due to steam lags? An error in my code? The fact I haven't spent $5 on the account to unlimit it?

```
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');
const SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
const TradeOfferManager = require('steam-tradeoffer-manager');

const secrets = require('./2fasecrets.json');

const client = new SteamUser();
const community = new SteamCommunity();
const manager = new TradeOfferManager({
    steam: client,
    community: community,
    language: 'en',
    pollInterval: 10000
});

const logOnOptions = {
  accountName: secrets.username,
  password: secrets.password,
  twoFactorCode: SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(secrets.shared_secret)
};

client.logOn(logOnOptions);

client.on('loggedOn', () => {
  console.log('Logged into Steam');
});

client.on('friendMessage', (steamid, message) => {
  console.log(`Message from ${steamid}: ${message}`);
});

manager.on('newOffer', offer => {
    console.log("New offer #" + offer.id + " from " + offer.partner.getSteamID64());
});
```